# Filter a table during a join

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to join a table that is filtered in the same query. I tried the following:

```
CREATE TABLE finaltable STORED AS ORC AS
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.col4, b.col5, b.col6
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT pid FROM table2 b WHERE dt = '2016-12' AND zip IN (94105, 925129, 90210, 90291, 90044, 10014, 10453)
ON a.pid = b.pid;
```

I got an error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 5:0 cannot recognize input near 'ON' 'a' '.' in expression specification
```

I thought the error was raised due to some alias issues, so I also tried:

```
CREATE TABLE finaltable STORED AS ORC AS
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, c.col4, c.col5, c.col6
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT pid FROM table2 b WHERE dt = '2016-12' AND zip IN (94105, 925129, 90210, 90291, 90044, 10014, 10453) c
ON a.pid = c.pid;
```

which also failed with:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 4:123 missing ) at 'c' near '<EOF>'
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve the above would be appreciated.

Comment: you are missing a closing `)` for the derived table `c`.

Comment: You haven't closed the subquery that's it

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the `SELECT` statement. Add a `)` before the c

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT pid FROM table2 b 
WHERE dt = '2016-12'
AND zip IN (94105, 925129, 90210, 90291, 90044, 10014, 10453)--->)<--- c
```

Comment: I think you  mean close `(SELECT`